# Online, free, survey tool with data export

Tags: gratis, web-apps, survey

I need a survey tool that will allow me to do the following:

- Create at least 50 questions (SurveyMonkey for example is free but limits you to 10 questions)
- Browser accessible and hosted
- Exports data to a .csv or .xls(x)
- Multiple question types: Multiple choice, text box, personal data, check boxes (can select multiple options)
- Is free

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Google forms](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/createforms.html) allows you to do this.

> Want to collect information quickly from your friends, customers, or colleagues?
>
> Create a form and collect the responses in a Google Docs spreadsheet. To get started view all templates or click on one of the categories below. It's free!

After creating a questionnaire, you can enable the data to be exported to a Google sheet. The Google sheet can then export to csv or excel.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/107) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it will be removed. For example review the requirements listed in the question.

Comment: I think that is what OP is looking for. Why a -1?

Comment: Not sure how I didnt know this was in Google but thanks, this should work.

Answer (score 3):

LimeSurvey - https://www.limesurvey.org/en/ - is excellent and has more features than the other answers so far. It's open source and you have to host it yourself. But there may be hosted versions of the sort you're looking for. It has all your other features.

Answer (score 0):

### [Excel Online](http://office.com)

- There is no limitation on the amount of questions.
- It is hosted on OneDrive and accessible by a link you can share.
- The data is *natively* embedded in an Excel document. You can therefore use any Excel feature you like, for example, a diagram can be created to reflect the survey's result.
- You can choose between the following answer types:

  - Text
  - Paragraph text
  - Number
  - Date
  - Time
  - Yes / No
  - Selection (checkboxes)
- It is free. You need a free Microsoft Account (such as a Hotmail or an Outlook.com address).